# Problem of positioning and size of the additional text on tikz/gnuplot figures

Tags: tikz-pgf, positioning, nodes, gnuplot

I want to at my legend using tikz environment on top of my figures generated with gnuplot. I am happy with the result when I comment the part `\node[anchor=center, text width=0.39cm, xshift=0cm, yshift=0cm] at (-6.0,1.0) {$sin(x)$};`. My figure is fitting nicely to the pdf document but it has no legend (I do not want to create my legend with gnuplot).

However with this line my figure is shifting to the right of the pdf. It cause an empty space on the left side of my picture. I realize its size is changing when I move the `\node` to the different negative positions on x direction. I think, I am missing something trivial about the size of the `\node`. And ideas? 
Should I use `\draw` instead of `\node`?

*Ps: I tried to put gnuplot part of my code into the another `\node` to be sure everything is on the same coordinate system which did not help my problem.*

**My present work is;**

```
\documentclass[12pt]{standalone}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{gnuplot-lua-tikz}
\usepackage[shell]{gnuplottex}
\thispagestyle{empty}
\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}
  \begin{gnuplot}[terminal=tikz,terminaloptions={size 14cm, 8cm}] 
     plot sin(x) w lines notitle
  \end{gnuplot}

  %I do not have any blank area without following line
  \node[anchor=center, text width=0.39cm, xshift=0cm, yshift=0cm] at (-6.0,1.0) {$sin(x)$}; 
  \end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

Result with a huge blank part on the left:
[image]

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX!  The node is included in the bounding box, try setting an explicit bounding box.

Comment: @trblnc_dsg Out of curiosity: What changes, if you add the option terminaloptions={nopicenvironment size 14cm, 8cm}?

Comment: @John with `terminaloptions={nopicenvironment size 14cm, 8cm}`, blank part still there. Looks like reference coordinates are changed somehow, cause position of the _sin(x)_ by itself.

Comment: @trblnc_dsg Hm okay. I think a solution using gnuplottex would be the following: Use the patch from http://sourceforge.net/p/gnuplot/feature-requests/409/ on gnuplot-lua-tikz.lua, then use `set label center "" at graph 0.5,0.1 font ',gp refnode,name=mynode1'` and use `\node[anchor=center, text width=0.39cm, xshift=0cm, yshift=0cm] at (mynode1) {$sin(x)$};`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Working example without the problem mentioned above, using explicit bounding box as recommended by @Andrew Swann;

```
\documentclass[12pt]{standalone}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{gnuplot-lua-tikz}
\usepackage[shell]{gnuplottex}
\thispagestyle{empty}
\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}
  \draw [draw=none,use as bounding box] (0cm,0cm) rectangle (14cm,8cm);{
    \begin{gnuplot}[terminal=tikz,terminaloptions={size 14cm, 8cm}] 
      plot sin(x) w lines notitle
    \end{gnuplot}
  };

  \node[draw=none, text width=1cm] at (-5.0,1.0) {$sin(x)$}; 
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

Also have a look for alternative method: [Clipping](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/200084/tikz-bounding-box-too-big)